# React Ag grid 2 master details in one grid for 2 different columns

Tags: reactjs, frontend, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to create 2 master details in react for 2 columns in one grid (not nested)
[example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6dth.png)

This is an example that i've seen for vanilla js :

https://blog.ag-grid.com/column-drill-down-using-master-detail-ag-grid/

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ag-grid-52eyso?file=index.js

but I need to know how can I do this in reactjs or should I even do that? Does it decrease the performance?

Help me If you can or my boss would kill me ❤

I tried to do it like normal master/detail as ag-grid documents provided for simple Master/Detail for both of columns.
but now they're opening and closing together and nothing happened.
I used

cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer'

for both columns and it did not work as I expected.

[what it look like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdwcv.png)

Comment: You seem to be asking for an opinion.  Please provide a succinct snippet of your own code showing what you have tried and a description of what you EXPECT and what is ACTUALLY occuring.

Comment: I've provided the js form of what I want in Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ag-grid-52eyso?file=index.js
this is ok for js.
I just want to know how can I do this (Multiple Master Details for specific columns not just row) in aggrid for REACTJS.